# Create a symbolic link of directory in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, terminal, symlink

Below is my code for creating a symlink of a directory:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/nginx/conf/ /etc/nginx
```

I already created the directory `/etc/nginx`.  I just want the contents of the source directory (`/usr/local/nginx/conf/`) to be in the contents of the target directory (`/etc/nginx`). But when I execute the code, `/etc/nginx` contains a directory called `conf`, instead of the contents of `conf`. That directory contains the contents I want, but in the wrong location.

Why did it put a directory in the target folder, instead of just putting the contents of the directory in the target folder?

Comment: You can also use Files (default file browser). Right click on the folder you want to link > "Make Link" option. It will create linked folder which you can move and rename as you need.

Comment: Use linux `bind mount` feature. [example](http://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

This is the behavior of `ln` if the second arg is a directory. It places a link to the first arg *inside it*. If you want `/etc/nginx` to be the symlink, you should remove that directory first and run that same command.

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/weird-behavior-of-gnu-ln

Comment: That Unix.SE link resolves back here. Seems we got a circular dependency.

Answer (score 32):

That's what `ln` is documented to do when the target already exists and is a directory. If you want `/etc/nginx` to **be** a symlink rather than **contain** a symlink, you had better not create it as a directory first!

Comment: Your answer only makes sense in the context of the reader already knowing the answer. It is useless to anyone who would ask the question

Comment: Can I actually create a symlink to a root of a mounted USB device (thus I cannot erase this folder first)?

Comment: @GrigoryKornilov you can create a symlink *to* anything you want, including something that doesn't exist. This question was rather about the place where the symlink is created (not where it points to). A particular pathname in the filesystem is either a regular file or it is a directory or it is a symlink (or it is a socket or pipe or device). It cannot *be* more than one of those things at the same time (i.e. you cannot have more than one distinct file with the exact same name).

Answer (score 12):

In script is useful something like this:

```
if [ ! -d /etc/nginx ]; then ln -s /usr/local/nginx/conf/ /etc/nginx > /dev/null 2>&1; fi
```

it prevents before re-create "bad" looped symlink after re-run script

Comment: Excellent! This is the exact solution.  no need to create the directory if it already existing. It's a real good tweak to hard link and sink it in the blackhole(/dev/null)