# Set alternate path for sublime snippets?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

I'm writing JS and I need sublime to look in another path where I keep my snippets.  I don't want to manually copy them over.  I just want sublime to look for them in another location.

How can I achieve this?

I looked in `Preferences.sublime-settings` and did not see any thing.

Comment: I would recommend having a *Snippets* folder in your *Packages – User* directory, and then just keeping all your snippets there. Sublime will be able to see all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply create a symbolic link?

```
ln -s source_dir target_dir
```

Comment: I thought about that but there will be x files.  Can you use ln on folders?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104337/create-a-symbolic-link-of-directory-in-ubuntu